# Hide multiple rows in excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to hide all rows containing the value "xx" in column A and not hide the rows containing "a" in column A. The range is from A8:A556. This macro needs to be triggered by a change in cell C4.

Any idea why it is not working? Here's the current attempt:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$4" Then

    If Range("A8:A555").Value = "xx" Then
        Rows("8:555").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("A8:A555").Value = "a" Then
        Rows("8:555").EntireRow.Hidden = False

     End If
   End If

End Sub
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Hey Fixer1234, Here is the detail:

- "xx" and "a" may not exist together if the macro works correctly.
- Only "xx" rows must be hidden
- "xx" values are not in combination with values that cannot be hidden.
- "a" values are not in combination with values that must be hidden.
- there are other rows that do not contain "xx or "a" that don't need to be hidden (should I add an "a" to these columns or completely remove the IfElse?).
- "xx" row contain other formulas, a blank result from the formula means the row must be hidden.
- "a" rows have the same formula but it produces a result and must not be hidden.

Run-time error '13': type mismatch 
and then the debug goes to the first
 `If Range("A8:A555").Value = "xx" Then`

Comment: Can there be both "xx" and "a"?  Neither?  If either is possible, what is supposed to happen?  Are there values other than "xx" for which it must be hidden?  Are there values other than "a" for which it must not be hidden?  Is it the case that for "xx" it **must** be hidden, but there are other values for which hidden or not hidden is optional?  Is it the case that it **must** be not hidden for "a", but there are other values for which hidden or not hidden is optional?  Could "xx" be in combination with other values that must be not hidden?  (cont'd)

Comment: Could "a" be in combination with other values that must be hidden?  These are all elements that aren't explained, that could affect whether you get what you want and whether your logic might be unnecessarily complicated.  If all records contain either "xx" or "a" but not both and there are no other values driving hidden or not hidden, you only need to test one of the values.  If it is possible for there to be unintended exceptions, the better logic would be to raise a warning if anything else is encountered.

Comment: Can you also clarify in what way your code is not working, and relate that to the values present that are being checked?

Comment: @fixer1234 added an update cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can't test all the values in a range using `Range("A8:A555").Value = "xx"`.  It will throw a Type Mismatch error.

You need to loop through each cell in the range and test individually if its `Value` equals "xx".

To make the code run faster, don't hide rows as you detect them but build up a `Range` of `Ranges` to be hidden then hide them all at once.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cel As Range
Dim RangeToHide As Range

    'Test if Target is C4
    If Not Intersect(Target, [C4]) Is Nothing Then
        'Loop through each cell in range and test if it's "xx"
        For Each cel In Range("A8:A555")
            If cel = "xx" Then
                If RangeToHide Is Nothing Then
                    'Initialise RangeToHide because Union requires at least 2 ranges
                    Set RangeToHide = cel
                Else
                    'Add cel to RangeToHide
                    Set RangeToHide = Union(RangeToHide, cel)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        RangeToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this VBA code as Standard Module, will help you to Hide all rows having either `XX` or `xx` in Column `A`.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$4" Then

Dim i As Integer
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    For i = 8 To 255

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "XX" Or Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "xx" Then
    Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If


    Next i
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

**N.B.**

No need to use any code to Unhide rows having `a` or `A`, since already are Visible. And above all the used code is hiding specific Rows in Column `A`.

Answer (score 0):

How do I hide separate rows!?
This is how I think:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1 = False Then
    [15:15].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    [3:3].EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    [15:15].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    [3:3].EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

Best Regards
Mattias

Comment: Why to do you think it might work? You don't know but just think, correct?